# Generating completely different UUID for MySql

Tags: mysql, uuid

I have seen other similar questions on SO but what I am asking here is not answered there.

I have a field called `GUID` on my table that is a primary key.

I want this field to be populated with a random UUID every time a recorded is inserted.

So, I have created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `GUID` char(40) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(`GUID`) 

) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `t_GUID` BEFORE INSERT ON `myTable`
 FOR EACH ROW begin
 SET new.GUID := (SELECT uuid());
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I have inserted 4 new records to this table and these are the UUIDs added to the entries:

- ae353781-9022-11ea-b775-1866daed31d4
- ae353a23-9022-11ea-b775-1866daed31d4
- ae353b4e-9022-11ea-b775-1866daed31d4
- ae353c26-9022-11ea-b775-1866daed31d4

except for 3 digits these are basically the same UUID.

How do I generate completely different UUIDs that are unique for the table as new records are being inserted?

Comment: Why are you using MyISAM?

Comment: Why do you ask? This is how all tables are created by my phpMyAdmin... why?

Comment: Your version must be rather old. I rarely see MyISAM tables these days because the benefits of InnoDB (data integrity) are generally considered to vastly outweigh those of MyISAM (occasional, modest performance increase)

Comment: Glad to know that. Thanks. I will update the tables to InnoDB. BTW, do you know the answer to what I am asking? thanks.

Comment: Also if it was me I'd just store an AI for the PRIMARY KEY. If there's some business information that you're trying to protect then hide the AI from the public, and have a separate UNIQUE public id (it doesn't need to be universal) generated by whatever means you desire

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, yes a guid or uuid is not designed to be hard to predict.  It is only designed to be unique which is a difficult enough task.

Having large primary keys like this will really eat up space, which decreases performance.

I wouldn't recommend it for anything other than a last resort.  Usually people will use guid's for keys when they are planning in advance to shard data into multiple tables.

Another argument against doing this is that obfuscation is not security.  If there is a problem from a security standpoint with someone seeing something they shouldn't because they accessed for example a url with `id=3`, then that same problem exists if the url is `id=ae353c26-9022-11ea-b775-1866daed31d4`.  The application should not allow someone to access `id=3` if they should not be able to access it.

With that said, one workaround used for this type of scheme would be to hash the input.

You could use the uuid concatenated with some of the data from the row, and perhaps a timestamp, and something random and run that through sha1() for example.  It will produce a large 40 character hex string.

There is a chance of a collision, so you would probably want to check and recover from that.

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `GUID` char(40) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(`GUID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `t_GUID` BEFORE INSERT ON `myTable`
 FOR EACH ROW begin
 SET new.GUID := (SELECT SHA1(CONCAT(new.first_name, RAND(), UUID(), new.last_name, NOW())));
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Note that the number in parentheses following an INT declaration is almost meaningless in MySQL. And it's decidedly odd to have a column called id that *isn't* the PRIMARY KEY. But I agree with the entirety of the preamble.

Comment: Agree, the int(6) is basically useless. The mysql command line client will limit the size of the display of an integer to that number of digits, but I would never that syntax in a table definition myself.  It was simply copied from the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The uuid() function generates UUIDv1, which is defined in a way that is fairly predictable. If you generate a bunch of new values very quickly, they will only vary by a few bits—but they are still guaranteed to be unique.

If you want unpredictable values, then you need to switch to a function that generates UUIDv4. This is only statistically unique, but unless you are generating billions of values per second for billions of years, it's good enough in practice.

Aside: you may want to consider storing UUIDs as BINARY(16) to save space and improve search efficiency. You can use a generated column to get the text version if you need that inside the DB for troubleshooting.